# Error when rebuilding SELinux policy after adding rule to type enforcement (.te) file

Tags: security, selinux

I am going through this [guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/using_selinux/writing-a-custom-selinux-policy_using-selinux) which allows me to create a custom SELinux policy for an application and restrict unconfined access to the kernel system files.

On Step 9, I need to add a rule to the Type Enforcement file (mydaemon.te) and rebuild and reinstall the policy by running the **mydaemon.sh** script.  Unfortunately, I came across an **ERROR 'unknown type var_log_t' at token ';'** as shown below.

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-6-46 ~]$ sudo ./mydaemon.sh
Building and Loading Policy
+ make -f /usr/share/selinux/devel/Makefile mydaemon.pp
Compiling targeted mydaemon module
mydaemon.te:26:ERROR 'unknown type var_log_t' at token ';' on line 4010:
    
allow mydaemon_t var_log_t:file { open write getattr };
/usr/bin/checkmodule:  error(s) encountered while parsing configuration
make: *** [/usr/share/selinux/devel/include/Makefile:157: tmp/mydaemon.mod] Error 1
+ exit
```

I tried using another type such as **var_t**, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `allow mydaemon_t var_log_t:file { open write getattr };` to your type enforcement file, you also need to add in the same file, in the require section, a type `var_log_t` and a class with the object `file` and the verbs `open write getattr`.

So it would looks like:

```
require {
    type mydaemon_t;
    type var_log_t;
    class file { open write getattr };
}

#============= mydaemon_t ==============
allow mydaemon_t var_log_t:file { open write getattr };
```